# Stop form from submitting automatically

Tags: html

The search field within the form below is connected to my backend, and automatically submits the form once an item is placed into the field.

In this instance, when it the user types a location, it automatically renders on the map.

How can I stop it from submitting unless the user has pressed submit?

Below is the form, and how I cam calling the google api

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input  id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search a city">
                <input  type="text" placeholder="Category">
                <button class="searchbutton" type="button">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>



<script src="script.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=createMap&libraries=places&key=API_KEY async defer></script>
```

and then here is the `script.js` file which renders the map

```
var map;

function createMap () {
    var options = {
        center: { lat: 43.654, lng: -79.383},
        zoom: 10,                
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);


var input = document.getElementById('search');

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds ());

});

var markers = [];

searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length === 0)
    return;

    markers.forEach(function (m) { m.setMap(null);});
    markers = [];

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    places.forEach(function (p) {
        if (!p.geometry)
        return;

        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: p.name,
            position: p.geometry.location
        }));

        if (p.geometry.viewport)
        bounds.union(p.geometry.viewport);
        else
        bounds.extend(p.geometry.location);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'blue'
    })
});

}
```

Comment: That should not submit the form. Please provide a [mcve]. (Your HTML does have an error: you're not closing your `<div>`, but that is probably not the issue.)

Comment: @Ivar updated with further details

Comment: Why do you believe the form is being submitted?  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q0e1bm2y/) with the code in your question (with the HTML errors fixed), it works as I expect.

Comment: @geocodezip yes the html error was a copy error, but the form is being submitted because when you type in a location it automatically renders a map, without pressing search

Comment: That isn't the form being submitted to the server, it is the `SearchBox` working as designed.

Comment: @geocodezip whats the alternative then?

Comment: What do you want to happen? The JavaScript code you wrote is adding the marker to the map when it is selected from the drop down, if you don't want that to happen, remove that code.

Comment: @geocodezip I want the user to be be able to select a location, without it automatically submitting, as there will be a second option they will be selecting from to further define results. 

Yea, I see that the JS is wrong, as it is listening for the searchbox, but how can i rectify so that it only listens for the button click, but the autocomplete still remains intact? Removing that code removes the functionality

Comment: I didn't mean to imply remove **all the code**, just the code that puts the marker on the map (the code in the `places_changed` event handler function  `searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {});`)  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q0e1bm2y/1/)